# Monitoring open/closed-circuit on a mains line

Tags: isolation

I am building a custom refrigerator control circuit.
The refrigerator is solely powered from a battery source, using an inverter.
For power savings, the inverter should be off when the motor is not running.

The thermostat closes when the temperature is too high. This would normally start the motor. But the inverter is off.

How can I know when the thermostat is closed/open?

There is no voltage in the circuit, so it would be trivial to provide 5V to test for the closed circuit, except that this wouldn't be isolated, which could be problematic when the inverter is on.

The circuit should:

- take advantage of the internal thermostat (cannot be seperated from motor/mains power)
- should be properly isolated (e.g. induce a 5VAC signal that can be measured via a zero cross circuit, but without risk of back-current)
- can be powered from a 5V/12V source

Currently, I have a seperate temperature sensor, and it's a simple solution, but I'd prefer to use the thermostat. Also, the thermostat cannot be seperated, because it's built-in.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fA3Seu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You have changed your question to say that the thermostat can't be removed yet you show that you are attempting to measure voltage across it while in circuit. That means that you must have access to it so why can't you remove it and use it on the DC?

Comment: Your question appears confused. If the Thermostat is Open and the relay is in series with the Invertor as shown ….how is the relay going to reduce the idle power of the invertor??  By turning OFF the invertor do you really mean switching off the DC input to the invertor?

Comment: I've built a circuit for myself, but I was thinking to generalize it and make a small-batch non-profit circuit for other offgrid'ers. But I don't expect that others would be willing to modify their refrigerator too much, so I thought it would be ne nice if there was a simple way to utilize the typical circuit of a standard low cost fridge. This would require the measuring circuit as above. Indeed, the thermostat could be removed from the circuit, but then the internal light stops working, thus requiring changes to the fridge anyway.

Comment: A production run changes the requirements again. Why was this not in the original question? Use the idea of Figure 2 in my answer but, instead of monitoring the motor with a relay, monitor the DC current drawn by the inverter. That way it will work with any fridge plugged into the inverter mains socket. I'm not going to update the answer anymore as I seem to be chasing a moving target.

Comment: That's a fair point, I'll try to formulate it more clearly in a new question.

Comment: No, fix this one instead.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbUXm1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) What you've got. (b) Simple solution. (c) Better solution.*

The simplest solution is to rewire to use the thermostat as the inverter power switch.
The thermostat is unlikely to have a good DC rating as it is designed to switch AC at much lower currents than the DC current required by the inverter.

To protect the thermostat and prevent malfunction use (c). Here a relay (coil voltage to match battery voltage) is switched by the thermostat. A contact of the relay (rated for the maximum DC current of the inverter) switches on the inverter.

---

Update after new constraints were added to the question.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2forFm2.png)</sup>

*Figure 2. Periodic test circuit.*

As you have probably realised, you can't test the thermostat wihout powering up the circuit. Any low-voltage test circuit you add across the thermostat will be destroyed if the thermostat opens when power is switched on.

With Figure 2 you can enable the inverter periodically, wait a second or two for it to power up and then check the status of RLY1. If it's on then you know that you should keep the inverter running until RLY1 drops out due to the thermostat opening (because the fridge has got cold again). If during the periodic test the relay isn't on then shut down the inverter.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I agree that Figure 2 is probably the easiest approach. It would probably require a test every 10 minutes, for 10 seconds, thus wasting about 1 minute of running time per hour, or in my case, about 5 Wh per day, for a fridge that costs 300-500 Wh per day to run. It would be trivial to test whether there's power running through the thermostat, and not turning off the inverter until the power is not there anymore. I'm not sure if it might cause wear on the inverter though (144 power cycles per day).

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I feel that these are solutions that modify the problem, rather than solving the original problem. I agree that these are simple solutions, but I am specifically interested in knowing whether there is a smart way of solving the original problem, for example, it might be that there exists a cheap IC that can produce an isolated AC signal on the same mains line, that is then detectable. That would be the ideal solution.