# How to tell if the switch is open or closed on a mains line?

Tags: isolation

Imagine a circuit that may or may not be connected to mains voltage.

If mains is connected, it is trivial to determine if the switch is closed, by using a zero-cross detector circuit.

If mains is not connected, it is necessary to power the switch.
How can it be powered in an isolated way, from a 5V/12V source, such that the state of the switch can be determined?

The circuit should not be affected by whether mains is connected or not.

Is this possible?

**My question is strictly for this circuit. Nothing can be changed.** The monitoring circuit can only be connected with the two wires as illustrated in the diagram.

I've voted to close my [original question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/433700/monitoring-open-closed-circuit-on-a-mains-line?noredirect=1#comment1083711_433700) because it ended up off-topic and unrelated to what my actual question was.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fXpzWT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: if 'nothing can be changed', then your monitoring circuit has no means to signal its detection state to anything else. I presume you will want to control something based on your detection of the switch state. What is that something connected to?

Comment: @Neil_UK I'm trying to avoid adding unnecessary details about the surrounding environment, because in my original question, it ended up making the problem unclear. For this question, using only the two wires of the monitoring circuit, is it possible to safely add a signal, e.g. 5 VAC, together with mains (whether it's live or not), to easily detect whether the switch is closed?  Ideally using a simple IC with isolation. (I'm assuming 5 VAC  would be a necessary byproduct of using a tiny transformer for isolation, but I guess it could also be a DC circuit)

Comment: The OP is trying to detect whether the fridge thermostat is open or closed and use that signal to turn on a battery-powered mains inverter.

Answer (score 0):

You monitoring circuit can try send a tiny current though the endpoints and if it succeeds the switch is closed. The circuit must be isolated from the mains.

At the same time the circuit must be able to withstand the full mains voltage. A simple resistor with voltage clamp will do that.

Of course if the clamp voltage is detected the switch is open...

Comment: I was thinking that it should be possible to send an additional signal to the mains, i.e. creating 5 VAC by using some simple IC that provides isolation? Is any such solution common, simple and safe?

Comment: You can probably superimpose a signal in the 100+kHz range and isolate it with some Class-Y's. There's no guarantee that nothing will leak through the big loop through the transformer, though, but probably massively attenuated.

Answer (score 0):

The standard for this circuit is something like

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feMA6Y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

D1 - D6 are power diodes which can handle (nominally) 15 amps, or whatever the AC circuit is fused for. D7 and D8 are LEDs which are part of a bidirectional optocoupler, and should be IR LEDs for low Vf. Q1 is the detector phototransistor of the optocoupler.

Using diodes to sense the current will produce a voltage drop of 3-5 volts, which should not be a problem for most AC circuits.

Comment: The problem that the OP hasn't stated is that the AC power is actually an inverter. This was the subject of his/her [previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/433700/monitoring-open-closed-circuit-on-a-mains-line). The OP is trying to figure out how to turn on the inverter when the fridge thermostat closes.

Answer (score 0):

The monitor circuit could contain a high frequency AC generator, at some frequency well above 50Hz, and with an output impedance that's relatively high (so it can withstand being short circuited).  It would also contain a voltmeter that will detect high frequency AC.

This monitor would be connected to the rest of the circuit through low-value capacitors.  The value of those capacitors would be such that they have a very high impedance at 50Hz, and low impedance at the frequency chosen.

If the switch is on, it will short-circuit the AC generator and the voltmeter will rwad low.  If the switch is off, the voltmeter will read high.